# Bootstrap timeline picture alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, timeline

I want to integrate a timeline on a website and used this code as a basis for the timeline: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive

I further expanded the snippet by adding pictures. In the beginning everything worked great with two pictures (in the first row), three were also okay(below the first two), but as soon as a forth came, latter suddenly appeared one row below instead of next to the third under the second.

html:

```
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>


<li class="timeline-inverted">
            <div class="timeline-panel">
                <div class="timeline-heading">
                    <h4 class="timeline-title">1981-1990</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline-body">
                    <p>Some text</p>
                    <p>Some more text</p>
                </div>
            </div><div class="timeline-picture-body">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
                <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
            </div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
/*body*/
body {
 background-color: white;
}
.panel {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
.panel-extra {
 padding: 10px 0;
 margin-top: 25px;
 background-color: lightgrey;
 border-radius: 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.box {
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 border-bottom-width: 3px;
 border-bottom-color: lightgrey;
 border-bottom-style: solid; 
}
/*Timeline*/

.timeline {
list-style: none;
padding: 20px 0 20px;
position: relative;
}

.timeline:before {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 3px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
}

.timeline > li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline > li:before,
.timeline > li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    }

.timeline > li:after {
    clear: both;
    }

.timeline > li > .timeline-panel {
    width: 46%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
        float: right;
    }

    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-right-width: 15px;
        left: -15px;
        right: auto;
    }

    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
        border-left-width: 0;
        border-right-width: 14px;
        left: -14px;
        right: auto;
    }
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body: before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        right: -15px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: 15px solid transparent;
        border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
        border-right: 0 solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
        content: " ";
    }
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body: after {
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        right: -14px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-top: 14px solid transparent;
        border-left: 14px solid #fff;
        border-right: 0 solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
        content: " ";
    }
    .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-picture-body {
        float: left;
    }
.timeline-title {
 margin-top: 0;
 color: inherit;
}

.timeline-body > p,
.timeline-body > ul {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.timeline-body > p + p {
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.timeline-images-right {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.timeline-images-left {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 40%;
 float: right;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
.padding-bottom {
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.align {
 display: block;
}

/*fonts*/
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 220px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
.box h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: black;
 padding-top: 30px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
h2{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2.3em;
 color: black;
}
p {
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

I already tried deleting any `padding` and changing the `display` and `vertical-alignment` property.

For clarification, the problem looks like this: [image: problem]

If you need further parts of the code, please tell me, I am happy to upload them as well.

I appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Comment: There's something wrong with the rest of the code you haven't included - see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaLfLbg5/) - it's your code, just with placeholder images, and it works fine.

Comment: I added the rest of the code for this part. However, it seems like jsfiddle is not able to show how it would look only regarding the bootstrap part.

Comment: Could you post the header part of your code? So we know all external resources and styles?

Comment: This is what you meant, right?

Comment: Yup - just if you could add the contents of styles.css as well :)

Comment: Ok, uploaded this part as well :)

Comment: Ok this is kinda strange - because with all your code (including the bootstrap css) it still works ok - see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaLfLbg5/1/) - oh and for next time just paste your code into a jsfiddle or similar instead of adding the four spaces to everything! Is there any chance you would paste all of your html into the jsfiddle, update it and paste the link back here?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm leaving so wont be around to help you for awhile... but I went to the link at the top, and copied the example, then added your css and html, and it works - see here -> [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mam86rdL/)

Comment: I pasted everything in there and it works. The problem is the browser. In Safari the site it works, in Chrome it does not.

Comment: I suppose there's no way you could provide a link to the actual page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113765/discussion-between-elina-and-calvt).

Answer (score 0):

It is not the perfect solution as it does not target the initial browser problem but this way the pictures no longer behave weird:

I have added a `container`between the rows. It must be a bootstrap `container`, with all the other elements and classes that I tried it did not work.

```
<div class="timeline-picture-body">
                        <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="img/tl7.jpg">
                        <img class="timeline-images-left padding-bottom" src="img/tl8.jpg">
                    <div class="container"></div>
                        <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="img/tl9.jpg">
                        <img class="timeline-images-left align" src="img/tl10.jpg">
                </div>
```